# Recursive Craft Charms?

Tags: exalted, exalted-3e

The Craft tree in exalted is kind of hard in the Power category. Now I have a trouble if my recursive interpretation is right.

- Let's assume a dexterity 5 intelligence 5 craft (something) 5 Solar. So the base pool is 10 dice. Atop it is a craft supernal, so essence is of no concern unless it is referenced for dice pools/boni
- 10 extra dice for 10 motes by using the excellency
- 2x6 motes for *Flawless Handiwork Method II* (p297)

  - Reroll any 10 and 6 (increase the pool)
- 4 motes, 4 silver, 4 gold, 4 white for *Experiential Conjuring of True Void* + *First Movement of the Demiurge*

  - 1 automatic success & (Essence) non-charm dice to the pool, if Essence >=3: also add (Intelligence) non-charm dice to the pool
  - count successful triplets of numbers (7, 8, 9, 10) - for each turn one non-successful die to a 10
  - check if this makes a triplet full, if yes: turn another one to 10
  - do rerolls for Flawless Handiwork Method
  - check for rerolls (FHM) & new triplets (FMotD)
- *Divine Inspiration Technique*

  - count successful dice, divide by 3, round down: roll this number of non-charm dice
  - count the *new* successes and apply DIT
  - apply FHM on all these new dice (recursively)
  - apply FMotD on the new dice & apply FHM on these (which can lead to recursion)
- 2 motes 1 white for *Surpreme Masterwork Focus III* (p297)

  - double 7 = count the number of successful dice after all the manipulations and multiply by 2

Am I correct in applying this multiple times recursive method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, yes, that double or triple recursive behavior seems to be intended.

With the listed charms the handy http://wiseartificersinsight.com/ tells us that a single (terminus 1) difficulty 5 roll will result in the following results over a milllion tests:

> Mean threshold successes per attempt: μ = 58.52
>
> Standard Deviation of threshold successes per attempt: σ = 23.72
>
> Median of threshold successes per attempt: 53
>
> Initial size of crafting die pools: 22

However, that is not yet the tip of the iceberg:

Adding Unbroken Image Focus, (Breach Healing Method), Mind Expanding Meditation, Divine Inspiration Technique, (Realizing the Form Supernal), Holistic Miracle understanding, and Sun-Heart Tenacity (and having made a legendary before the project), the starting pool becomes 32(or 34). It also becomes extra recursive/itterative in so many steps, that the following results happen:

> Mean threshold successes per attempt: μ ~ 1160-70
>
> Standard Deviation of threshold successes per attempt: σ ~ 140
>
> Median of threshold successes per attempt: 1155-1165
>
> Initial size of crafting die pools: 32

The downside is, that these extra charms cost extra:

You have to spend 3 more motes, 5 more silver and 1 more white craft XP for the base costs and atop that 1 silver, gold and white (which comes down to 7 silver to be handled before the roll using the prana shifting thing) for each successful dice on the *initial* roll to buy extra successes. The two charms you could add for repair just cost 12 more motes and a white point atop that price.